# How do you pull files from Android Work Profile Apps during Android Automation?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, adb

In Android if you need to pull files to laptop you need to run :

```
$ adb pull "/data/data/<packagename>/<file-name>" “<destination>”
```

But for Apps in Android Work Profile under Android Enterprise how do you pull files from the app sandbox for automation debug purposes.? Would there be any other location to save it to that can pulled during UIAutomator runs?

I am aware of the launchability : https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles#testing_tips

```
adb shell am start --user 10 \
                   -n "com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.testactivity" \
                   -a android.intent.action.MAIN \
                   -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```